# Generating an equivalence relation out of another relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm preparing for an exam in discrete mathematics and found the following question in my course materials.

Let c be the equivalence relation **generated** by $\{(6,3), (0,2), (2,1), (4,9), (8,3), (1,7)\}$ on [0,9]. Determine $[7]_c$.

I know how to determine $[7]_c$ once I have the equivalence relation. But how do I get the equivalence relation? What does this ***generated*** mean? I don't get it. Could you please give me an hint?

Comment: I suppose a sensible way to interpret it would be this: all given pairs are pairs of your relation, and then you add all other pairs required to make it an equivalence relation.

Comment: That sounds too simple

Comment: Well, that's exactly what we do when we generate topologic spaces. Not everything has to be hard, you know? :) The equivalence relation generated by any relation is the smallest equivalence containing it...

Comment: For example, since $(6,3)$ is there, then you must add $(3,6), (3,3), (6,6)$. It might help to draw a graph (and transitive closure thereof) to see the equivalence classes.

Comment: And since $(8, 3)$ is also there, you must add $(6, 8)$, and all the other relevant relations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one is given a subset  $S \subset A \times A$, then there is a 'smallest' 
equivalence relation $\sim$ such that if $(a,b) \in S$, then $a \sim b$. The
resulting equivalence relation is called the equivalence relation generated by $S$.
By smallest, I mean finest.

First, the relation  $\sim_* $ defined by $a \sim_* b$ **iff** $a,b \in A$ is
an equivalence class that is compatible with $S$.

Now suppose $E=\{ \sim_\alpha\}_\alpha$ is a collection of equivalence relations on $A \times A$, then we can define the
relation $\sim_E$ by $a \sim_E  b$ **iff** $a \sim_\alpha b$ for all $\alpha$.
(Note that $\sim_* \in E$ so $E$ is non empty.)

It is easy to establish that this is an equivalence relation.

So, let $E = \{ \sim | \sim \text{ is compatible with } S \}$ and let $\sim_E$
be the relation as defined above. Then $\sim_E$ is the smallest or finest equivalence relation that is compatible with $S$.

One way of generating the equivalence relation for a finite $A$ is to start with a graph that has vertices $A$ and add an undirected edge for each pair
$(a,b) \in S$. Now compute the transitive closure of the graph and read off the equivalence classes (the connected subsets).

So, one starts with 
\begin{eqnarray}
(6,3), (8,3) & &\\
(0,2), (2,1), (1,7)& & \\
(4,9) & &
\end{eqnarray} 
from which we can read off the equivalence classes $\{ 3,8,6 \}$,
$\{ 0,1,2,7 \}$, $\{4,9\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. But I don't see how to draw the graph. In the above example, is (0,2) the root? Sorry i'm really new to this. Could you please provide another example of a graph? This method sounds very interesting.

Comment: Just draw dots for each number $0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9$. Connect two dots if they are in the original list. Then group all the connected collections together. For example, there is a line joining $6,3$ and $8,3$ (and no others connected to all three dots) so that means $3,6,8$ lie in one class.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
(7\sim 1) \land (1 \sim 2) \Rightarrow 7 \sim 2
$$

$$
(7\sim 2) \land (2 \sim 0) \Rightarrow 7 \sim 0
$$

so:$[7]_C=\{0,1,2,7\}$